# Can we ask always include Arabic text of Ayah?

Tags: discussion, arabic, quran, faq-content

Can we ask whoever that gives just a translation of Ayah to include original text too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a variation of Dynamic's suggestion:

> Please always provide the English translation of Arabic quotations since not everyone is capable of reading Arabic and the posts should be useful for everyone. It is also strongly encouraged to include the original Arabic text when providing the English translation of a scripture, especially for an ayah or a hadith.

Comment: Yes. Same meaning but a lot better than what I wrote.

Comment: I suggest writing these suggestions as a list instead of as a quotation, and stressing (bolden) the: " It is also strongly encouraged to include the original Arabic text when providing the English translation of a scripture, especially for an ayah or a hadith." item of the list.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not. I think since the English translations vary, it's better to link to a website which includes both the original Arabic version and an English translation.

Answer (score 1):

Asalamu wa alaikum,

I don't see why not, I think it should be necessary to have the Arabic text of the Quran because it is the original language of the Quran, and English texts as Gigili vary, so we want to make sure that there is the reliable text even if no one can read it.  So I would say it should be necessary to have both the Arabic texts and a reliable translation, and as Gigili said it's better to link to a website which has both the Arabic and the English, in my opinion the website should be reliable and have almost all the languages because not everyone is Arabic or English.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should be necessary, but it should be highly encouraged. The rule should be:

> If you are only providing English texts of a scripture, *we greatly encourage* you to add an Arabic translation. If you are only providing Arabic texts of a scripture, you *must* add an English translation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answers are written in English for a predominantly English-speaking audience, I personally don't like to clutter my answers with Arabic text unless the exact literal translation of a word/phrase is important to the answer.

The Arabic text is readily available online, and whenever I quote an ayah from the Qur'an I add a link to Quran.com where the original text can be read.  I believe that this should be sufficient, and leaves the answers easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

We should not include Arabic text in the answer. The reason because

- No one reads Arabic *and* English. It will always be english.
- It take space and make the answer more complicated.
- A big portion of this site users do not know Arabic
- Reciting or reading the holy verse may need one to be in pure clean form which might not always be the case.
- It will scares non-Muslim because a simple answer can be complicated for them.
- This site is not only for Muslim only but for non Muslim also. It should care for both.

What we should include is

- Reference to the verse (required)
- And not just the verse but a brief explanation in our words how does it answer the question. Most of the time they are not clear in itself.